# Rewrite Rule working different than expected

Tags: redirect

We have our blog posts on a custom page with a custom pagination. For example a blog post name is url.de/postname instead of url.de/blog/postname.

Therefore we have a page /blog/ which has the pagination on it. The links from the pagination module like /blog/2/ lead to a 404 error page, because the /page/ part is missing.

I cannot edit the page urls - therefore i would like to use a redirect rule for this.

What i got till now:

```
function my_pagination_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '(([^/]+/)*blog)/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_pagination_rewrite' );
```

But this leads to /blog/2/page/2 --> 404.

How can i get this code to return /blog/page/2 or just return /blog/2/ (and show the content of /blog/page/2)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another answer because the rule is only a part of the problem.

Here is what I have tested and is working :

```
<?php
class BadRewritesRules {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('init', [$this, 'custom_post_types_rewrite_rules']);
        remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
    }

    public function custom_post_types_rewrite_rules() {
        add_rewrite_rule('(blog)/([0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
    }

}

new BadRewritesRules();
```

In reality, I used another URL and you can see it working here : https://tests.pierre-roels.com/bad-rewrite-rules/2/
You can use pagination and also view each "member" with the same slug.

But as I said, this is a poor solution in my opinion because we must remove the `template_redirect` action hook. It would be better to hook on the Laravel part to build links the right way :( Or maybe an `.htaccess` redirect ?

Don't forget to flush permalinks everytime you make a change. To do so, you can simply go to Settings > Permalinks and submit the page

Here is the solution with .htacess. Add this to your .htaccess :

`RewriteRule (blog)/([0-9]+)/? /$1/page/$2/ [R=301,L]`

and don't forget to fix you rule :
`add_rewrite_rule('(blog)/page/([0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');`.

I have made another test just for you : https://tests.pierre-roels.com/blog/2/

This solution allow you to not remove the `template_redirect` hook, it redirects the user the right end-url

Answer (score -2):

You should keep the slug page in your URL.
It is way more easier and better to read.

Here is something correct :

```
add_rewrite_rule( '(blog)/page/([0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

Comment: The slug /page/ is not present. That is part of the problem. I want to add it. ?!

Comment: I just read that you you use a custom pagination. So you need to add the "page" part in your links. Why don't you show your custom pagination code instead ?

Comment: As i already said: i cannot change this! This comes from Laravel. I am looking for a different solution.

Comment: There is too many missing information to help you out. How can you not change links ? How this is Laravel in Wordpress code and no hooks ? Why is there a redirection from your link URL to another URL that is more like a WP one ?
Anyway, you can start by rewrite you rule because you use `$matches[1]` and in your group it captures the first slash (/). According to my answer, you should start by using `(blog)` in your rule

Comment: The information is pretty clear: add_rewrite_rule for /blog/2 --> /blog/page/2

Comment: No this is not. Anyway, you should NOT have the begining slash in your matching group. Also, don't forget to flush rules everytime you make a modification in the rules. And finally, Wordpress will always try to redirect to the URL it knows so you must remove this redirect by using : `remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');`
I have tested it, it works but it is a very poor solution; you should use the WP URL hierarchy.